# Cannot build docker image for centos 7

Tags: docker, ssh, centos

I got a docker file like the next for building a centos 7 image

`FROM docker.io/centos`

`LABEL Remarks="This is a Dockerfile for Centos system cloudera based"`

`##libraries`

`RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in` *`; do [ $i ==`

`systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done);`

`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`*`;`
`rm -f /etc/systemd/system/`*`.wants/`*`;`
`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/`*`;`

`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/udev`*`;` 
`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/`*`initctl`*`;` 
`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/;`
`rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;`
`RUN yum update -y`
`RUN yum install sudo -y`
`RUN yum install openssh-clients -y`
`RUN yum install firewalld -y`
`RUN systemctl start firewalld`
`RUN systemctl enable firewalld`
`RUN yum install iptables -y`
`RUN yum install wget -y`
`RUN yum install libselinux-utils -y`
`RUN sudo yum install redhat-lsb-core -y`
`RUN yum install openssh-server openssh-clients openssh-askpass -y`
`RUN yum install deltarpm -y`
`RUN yum install policycoreutils -y`
`RUN yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`
`RUN yum install ntp`

`CMD [ "/sbin/bash" ]`

But after I try to run this docker file into my root, it gives me the next error

`Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':`

- ``` Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for ``http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container`` [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org] ```
  ``` Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for ``http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container`` [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org] ```

I got into docker hub and try to solve my problem by taking as reference other dockerfiles from the official image page of centos. However, there is no helpful resource in the website

Comment: Several of the packages you mention just won't work in Docker because it's a lightly isolated container environment sharing many resources with the host (`firewalld`, `ntp`, `iptables`).  Would a virtual machine running an unmodified CentOS image be a better match for your needs?

Comment: I see, but the problem is that even if I remove that packages, the error continues mostly when I run "yum update" or "yum install sudo". These two packages don't share resources with the host. Is there a way for building a custom centos container with only the basic commands?